# Низкоуровневый и высокоуровневый классы

Tags: классы

Иногда попадаются (`java`) такие понятия как "**низкоуровневый класс**" и/или "**высокоуровневый класс**".

Эти понятия имеют отношение к любому языку программирования оперирующему классами?

Возможно дать этим понятиям точную характеристику или точное определение?

Comment: Полагаю, зависит от контекста. "Низкоуровневый" может быть "финальным в дереве наследования", или "конкретным" в противовес абстрактым. Вопрос в том, какая цель преследуется вводом этой дихотомии, и насколько она оправдана, кроме как из академического интереса.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если говорить о java, то полагаю, что речь идет о классах ввода-вывода.

Низкоуровневые классы оперируют низкоуровневыми данными и работают с потоками байтов (например [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) и [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)),

а высокоуровневые — объектами (например [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) и [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)).

Высокоуровневые классы работают на базе низкоуровневых и отличаются по степени абстракции данных.

Для примера класс, который читает файл *побитово* будет низкоуровневым, а класс, который читает его *построчно* в Unicode — высокоуровневым.

А если пойти дальше, то может быть класс, который обращается к файлу сразу как к объекту xml и он будет еще более высокоуровневым по отношению к предыдущему.

Answer (score 3):

На практике понятие 'высоко' и 'низкоуровневый' чаще применяется к методам, а не к классам. Возможно это связано с тем, что такие понятия не определены в классическом ООП.

Но вы правы кое-где такие понятия встречаются и применительно к классам.
В java, в официальной документации, понятия низкоуровневый и высокоуровневые классы встречаются только в контексте классов ввода-вывода. Например классы
`'ByteArrayOutputStream'` и `'FileInputStream'` являются низкоуровневыми, а `'PrintStream'`, `'ObjectOutputStream'`, `'DataOutputStream'` - высокоуровневыми.
Также понятия высокоуровневый и низкоуровневые классы используются при описании Принципа Инверсии Зависимостей.

В целом, отличие одних классов от других в уровне абстракции. Разделение классов на низко и высокоуровневые классы - условное. На любой высокоуровневый класс можно придумать еще более высокоуровневый(абстрактный) класс и на любой низкоуровневый класс часто можно придумать еще более специфичный класс.

Answer (score 3):

Я обычно такие термины наблюдаю, когда речь идёт про инверсию зависимостей (DiP). Подробно можно почитать [тут](https://martinfowler.com/articles/dipInTheWild.html).

Если кратко, то низкоуровневый класс - это класс-рабочий, по сути, который какие-то действия совершает, в то время как высокоуровневый класс управляет этими "рабочими".

В DiP посыл в том, что высокоуровневые классs не должны зависеть непосредственно от низкоуровневых классов, а скорее получают объекты этих классов (или фабрик, которые их создают) заинджекченных в них, что выводит зависимость на уровень дженериков/интерфейсов.

К примеру, хотим мы выводить на печать символы. Высокоуровневый класс содержит логику по копированию, низкоуровневые: чтение с клавиатуры (`KeyboardReader`) и вывод на печать (`PrinterWriter`).

Высокоуровневый класс не должен зависеть от конкретной реализации. Ведь мы можем потом захотеть, к примеру, вывод не на принтер, а в файл (`FileWriter`) и т.п. Если делать плохо, то будет завязка на `PrinterWriter` и придётся всё переписывать.

Если делать правильно, то будет что-то вроде такого:

```
Высокоуровневый класс -> уровень абстракции -> низкоуровневый класс.
```